# Xcode 4.1.1 Crashes with Phonegap 2.0.0 and BarcodeScanner Plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, llvm-gcc

Upon "Adding Files to Project ..." within Xcode that are either .mm or .cpp, Xcode pauses then crashes.

I have Xcode 4.4.1 installed with Phonegap 2.0.0 properly setup.  I am using the Phonegap BarcodeScanner plugin from this master repo:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner

I changed the compiler from Apple LLVM 4.0 to **LLVM GCC 4.2** through Xcode -> (Target Build) -> Build Settings -> Build Options -> Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C.

The following Frameworks are also added properly:

- AVFoundation.framework
- AssetsLibrary.framework
- CoreVideo.framework
- libiconv.dylib

There are 4 files that are required for the BarcodeScanner to function properly:

- barcodescanner.js
- CDVBarcodeScanner.mm
- zxing-all-in-one.cpp
- zxing-all-in-one.h

Upon adding the "zxing-all-in-one.h" file to my plugins folder and "barcodescanner.js" to the www/ directory, everything is fine.  It's only when adding the .mm or .cpp files that Xcode crashes.

I have another MacBook Pro running Phonegap 1.7.0 and Xcode 4.4 and the barcode scanner works fine.  What's happened in Phonegap 2.0.0 that is crashing?  I looked through the FAQs and README documentation but couldn't find anything that worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in your specific version of Xcode.

Works perfectly fine for me in Xcode 4.3.2. Try downloading an older version of Xcode or the latest beta.

Comment: Everyone, Levi and I tried both 4.4.1 and 4.4 and the former crashes with any C++ based file.  If you're using Phonegap 2.0.0 make sure to have Xcode 4.4 installed.  We're assuming anything from 4.3.2 -> 4.4 will work.